# Maclaurin Series Question ??

Tags: taylor-expansion

Question: Find maclaurin series using the first few terms for:
$$\frac1{x^2}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-x\right)$$

The answer is $x/6$.

My working out so far:

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}= \frac{x-\frac{x^3}6+\cdots}{1-\frac{x^2}2+\cdots}$$

However, I cant seem to simplify it down to $x/6$?

Comment: What do you mean x/6? Does the book *just say* x/6, or are there more terms after wards?

Comment: says " x/6 ... " literally.

Comment: @Crescendo Of course, there will be higher order terms. I suppose the question means to find the lowest order term

Answer (score 1):

Use the series expansion$$\frac1{1-y}=1+y+y^2+...$$
All you need are the first two terms. You have $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{x-\frac{x^3}6+\cdots}{1-\frac{x^2}2+\cdots}$$ so take $y=\frac{x^2}2$. Then you get$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{x-\frac{x^3}6+\cdots}{1-\frac{x^2}2+\cdots}=\left(x-\frac{x^3}6+\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac{x^2}2+\cdots\right)$$
Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Thank you, how did you manage to get the series expansion of 1/(1-y)?, the rest makes sense.

Comment: It is quite commonly known. It is the maclaurin expansion about $0$: $$(1-x)^{-1}=(1-0)^{-1}+(-1)(-1)(1-0)^{-2}\cdot x+(-2)(-1)(1-0)^{-3}\cdot(\frac{x^2}2)+\cdots \\=1+x+x^2+\cdots$$

Comment: Also $\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+...+y^{n-1}$ so $\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+...+y^{n-1}+\frac{y^n}{1-y}$. Let $n \to \infty$ and use $y^n \to 0$. And if you integrate this you get the power series for $\ln(1-y)$.